# How to position a div to be visible but not count towards document width

Tags: html, css, layout

Today I came across a very nasty problem, I need to make the front-end layout for a website and it has a certain design element on the page that puzzled (even) me.

Now I am not exactly unfamiliar with html, css positioning, making layouts etc, so **please don't make 'guesses'** as to how I could solve it. I want a working example.

Here is a jsfiddle with my code and problem:
<s>http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/A9vzA/</s> http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/A9vzA/15/

**What is currently happening;**

The `#container` has a min-height of 100% (red background) width of 970px. This is the width the page must have as a minimum. The `#top` (lightbrown background) div is irrelevant for the problem but part of the design.

The problem lies in `#header` (purple background) which currently has a width of 1022px (too wide for 1024px resolution + a scrollbar, even with a maximized window) and a negative left margin to keep it centered on the container, which is what needs to happen. When the width of the screen width falls below 1022px a horizontal scrollbar apears as the thinnest element on the page is 1022px wide. (its behaviour is the same with position absolute and a negative left offset)

**What I want to have happening;**

I want the 'overflow' of `#header` over `#container` to dissapear into the sides and only get a scroll bar as the viewport gets below 970px wide. (If someone can rephrase this )

Let me be a little bit clearer on this:

- The 100% height layout needs to stay and be compatible with IE7+
- The header needs to be centered over the container, this is the reason it is inside it in my example but be my guest to take it out if that solves the problem.

  My example looks and acts correct as long as the viewport is large enough to accomedate the header.

  The trick is to make it look and act the same while the sides of header overflow into the sides of the viewport when the viewport is too slim to fit that header.

  Updated the example to make the change / centring a bit more obvious.

If possible I want the layout to support all the way down to IE6 though IE7+ will be fine. The final page will prompt to install Chrome Frame anyway. And ofcourse don't forget about Chrome, FF 3.5+.. (Opera?). Use of JS will not be acceptable, unless you can convince me that there is absolutely no other way, but jQuery will be present on the page.

Thank you for at least trying! (Challenge yourself! :D)

Comment: Are you trying to have a fixed header? You may be better off using position:fixed and it's JS alternative for ie6

Comment: I am not looking to have a `position: fixed` which scrolls along with the rest of the content staying at the top of the viewport the whole time if thats what you mean :)

Comment: What is the content of header? Could you separate the left and right part (26px to the left and to the right) from the content in the middle?

Comment: I give up on this one. I think it's not possible without JS

Comment: It's not the width that makes the problems, it's the right border of the right-most element. Make something centered and positioned. Pull it to the left: no problem, pull it to the right: problem!

Comment: can you give the image what the result your going to get? it will be easier to understand what you're going to achieve.

Comment: An image would take me quite a lot of time but I hope I cleared up some of the requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code worked for me in FF/Chrome/Safari/Opera. Can't test in IE because I'm on Mac now, but must work in IE 7+

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XVraD/3/

Base idea is to wrap #header in another container with "width: 100%; min-width: 970px;" and place in outside of #container, so it will do all the overflow to you.

**EDIT 2:** Solution that works in IE6: http://jsfiddle.net/XVraD/9/

**EDIT 3:** This version is fixed to have height 100% in modern browsers and old IE's:  http://jsfiddle.net/XVraD/9/

Comment: gets scrambled when you got content in your header that goes to the edges. 'aaaa' shifts to the right if you go under 1022px window width see http://jsfiddle.net/XVraD/1/

Comment: My bad. Made a fix for it: http://jsfiddle.net/XVraD/3/ (fixed #header width to 1022, and make, inner 950px width to make it more easy to spot).

Comment: Yeah, this really seems to work. I made a bit more obvious http://jsfiddle.net/XVraD/5/ not for IE6 though but that's a bonus

Comment: The left: 50% and margin-left: -512px did it

Comment: You probably can tweak it to work even in IE6 by emulating min-width with one of this methods: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/width.html , but I don't have access to Windows now to fine-tune it.

Comment: Added a possible IE6 code to the answer. But can't test it myself till tomorrow.

Comment: Last example didn't work in IE6, updated to example that works: http://jsfiddle.net/XVraD/9/

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks the [100% height layout](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html) of the page with the container. I actually had a solution much like this before I asked but I never did fix the height problem. The header must be out of flow for it to not interfere with the container.

Comment: Fixed height for FF/Chrome/Opera: http://jsfiddle.net/XVraD/15/ Can't check IE, don't have windows right now, but theoretically it must also work.

Comment: This indeed apears to be working correctly :) Will followup with a more rigorous test later.

Answer (score 5):

It is a hard one, the only real solution I can come up with is this that you use Media queries like this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 970px) {
  body, html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

It is not supported by old browsers, there you would need a Javascript!

Comment: +1 for providing a viable code example and possible solution, though not enough support (IE7 & 8 don't do media queries) :)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the best solution would be to restructure your HTML to put your header outside of the container.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="header">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer { ... }
.header { 
    max-width: 1022px;
    min-width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto; }
.container {
    width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/tJXHF/

Comment: Doesn't quite work as required. You make an example from stratch meaning much of the css needed for structuring other elements is now missing. The 'header' is also not overflowing into the left side but is instead pushed to the right when the window < the header. This is a key feature it needs to support. I can't use that unfortunately.

Comment: I do think I was clear that the sides / overflow should go up into the side**s** meaning this generic solution is way off and shouldn't actually score you points imo. I did explain that I am not a newb, this is a little too obvious of a solution to work tbh ;)

Comment: I'd be incredibly interested to see the design that requires such obscure markup.

Comment: @sg3s: you're being more than a little imperious towards somebody that's just trying to help.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/QrVJJ/

`#header` is positioned outside and above (with `z-index`) `#top`. It also gets `margin: 0 auto;` and the background is positioned `top center` with `min-width:970px` and `max-width:1022px`.

```
#header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index:5;
    min-width: 970px;
    max-width: 1022px;
    height: 201px;
    background: #390419;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: transparent url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_rScBRKlTdoE/TC6rNWAyD9I/AAAAAAABOTo/BWkJH9ymovo/s1600/IMG_9692.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about setting the header to have a min-width of 970px and a max-width of 1022px? There are ie hacks to make min and max width work. This would make make scrollbars appear after the viewport shrinks to below 970 and as you stretch the viewport the header would grow up until 1022 after which it would stay 1022.

Comment: Could mess up content inside the header, but that depends on whats inside. Otherwise a nice solution!

Comment: This doesn't quite work as the element containing `#header` is only 970px wide, so even if I keep the `#header` in regular flow its auto, and max width would be 970px. If I take `#header` out of regular flow with float or absolute positioning it will always have the min-width of 970px, since there won't be any reason to expand it to 1022px (there won't be anything forcing the element to this width), then there is the issue of centering `#header` over `#container` (you could have known this had you simply taken the 5 seconds to test this in jsfiddle)

Comment: I dont know what content you have in there but you could use overflow-x:hidden on the header and use fixed widths wider than 970 on the children elements. That would clip the content and stop it messing up. Another way could be to use % or em units on everything inside so that the inner content grows in proportion as header grows.

Comment: If it's not a fixed type element, why not use position relative, and z-index to keep it in flow and above the other elements. You could pull the elements under it up with negative top margin?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're describing because I don't think I am quite following the right strain of thought here?...

Comment: Hi @sg3s, can we pull `header` out of `container` ?

Comment: @MoinZaman as long as its behaviour stays the same it should be no problem.

Comment: You still haven't been able to provide a working example or test case which I did request and you did say you would make. For that you get a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Having this one in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/A9vzA/10/

Put an inner div inside the #header

The header has position relative and no float and with 970px

The inner div has position fixed and width 1022px and margin 0 -26px

--edit

but doesnot work in IE7

--edit

this works in IE7, too http://jsfiddle.net/A9vzA/11/ just add another inner div

The first inner div is position fixed and width 100% and text-align center

The second inner div is margin 0 auto and width 1022px

Can anyone test it in IE6

--edit

nope doesnot work if you got content in your #container. position fixed is no option

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work with content inside, because while scrolling horizontally at small resolutions it will also move header with window. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KDEJh/ scroll it to the right with small window width.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov you are right. this will not work in to ways. Look at my last edit

Comment: This will push the banner to the right over the container, which is not desired. I will update my question to include a picture to make it more obvious, but the state of the banner needs to stay centered over the container.

Comment: @sg3s That would be the best. But take a look at the solution of Alexey Ivanov (read the comments). I think he did it.

Answer (score 0):

sg3s, you sound like a tough customer but I thought I'd throw my hat in the ring.  None of us understands exactly what you need so please post the flattened design.

My assumption is that you need one or two layers with adjustable width behind a fixed 960px content container.  Using `float` on adjustable width containers is going to make it nearly impossible to do what you want.  Instead, use `postion: absolute` for a container holder (a.k.a. wrapper) and `position: relative` for the inner content containers.  No Javascript is necessary.

My recommendation is removing #header from the primary #content container and separating the background image from the #header so they can be rendered and positioned independently.

http://jsfiddle.net/dylanvalade/ZcejP/

Comment: The website you're working on indeed does do what I want, except that the centered part doesn't just contain a background image (some menu items, more specifically a shadow of the left most button, overflows into the left) and as you can also see in your own website, the image is actually centered on the viewport and not the fixed width middle content... making the background 'out of sync' with the middle.

Comment: I'm only this difficult because I am well capable of making up any conventional way you might want to try this and most of the unconventional ways. Unfortunately I cannot release the design itself because of an nda until the site goes live.. by then ofcourse.. meh!.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/HbxTQ/8/
```

Fullscreen:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/HbxTQ/8/embedded/result/
```

(I've not yet made it cross-browser, only tested it in Chrome. What to ensure I have the idea right first.)

Comment: I'm not TS, but you are almost right. But you need to center #header content, for it to crop from both sides simulationously. Right now when the resolution is less then 1022, header image is moved to the right. Plus you need to add top padding in content block to make content visible.